# ReactJS Component rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to have my webpage look similar to [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXxmo.png) 
Getting a hang on the syntax and conventions of having components can be simple, but as you can imagine, I'm not having a wonderful time. A lot of the code I've written below almost feels like pseudocode, and I'm not sure how closely I'm writing to it being real code.

Are there any red flags you can spot that would help improve this code?

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
    const prod_img = 'http://10.104.0.15/care-products.jpg';
    const prod_name = 'Bath and Body Products';
    const prod_description = 'The bath and body category includes all the items you need to take care of your skin and external body surfaces.';

  const ProductImage = (props) => {
        return <img src={props.prod_img} />;
    };

const ProductName = (props) => {
    return <h2>{props.prod_name}</h2>;
};

const ProductDesc = (props) => {
    return <p>{props.prod_description}</p>;
};

const Product = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <ProductImage image={prod_img} />
        <ProductName name={prod_name} />
        <ProductDesc description={prod_description}/>
    </div>
    );
```

};

```
ReactDOM.render(<Product />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Comment: Any specific areas? If not, your question is off topic and more 'code-review' (which has its own site).

Comment: in each of the function calls, I'm returning each of the corresponding variables, which aggregate into the product function. I have the ReactDOM enabled, but I'm trying to figure out why nothing's being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My recommendation would be to revise your question so it centers around the problem of it not rendering, since it just seems like a code review situation to me. Then, I and others would probably be able to go through and see what's wrong.

Comment: The function `ReactDOM.render` takes in two arguments, the component you want to render, and the corresponding place in HTML you want to render it: `ReactDOM.render(<Product />, document.getElementById('my-root-id-here'))`

Comment: Also, when passing props, the syntax should be `image={prod_img}` etc. as the curly braces indicate a JS expression

Comment: If you're using functional components, you access the argument `props`, not `this.props`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far; This has pretty much killed off any bugs I had earlier, but I am still at a loss with regard to the objects being displayed. Is it the return statements in each of my individual functions, or is it the Product function?

Comment: So each of your functions, `ProductImage`, `ProductName`, etc, are each **components**. They return some JSX that you want to display. Then we can compose those components into a large component, `Product`. Each is separate and reusable.

Comment: Hmm, so I removed the props from each of the return statements and it would have appeared to work. Was this what you were pointing towards? I had originally thought they were needed in most of my statements, but I guess that's not the case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props were called incorrectly.
If you have the following components (should be):

```
 <ProductImage image={prod_img} />
 <ProductName name={prod_name} />
 <ProductDesc description={prod_description}/>
```

Calling it in component should be like this:

```
const ProductImage = (props) => {
    return <img src={props.image} />;
};

const ProductName = (props) => {
    return <h2>{props.name}</h2>;
};

const ProductDesc = (props) => {
    return <p>{props.description}</p>;
};
```

To put it together:

```
const prod_img = 'http://10.104.0.15/care-products.jpg';
const prod_name = 'Bath and Body Products';
const prod_description = 'The bath and body category includes all the items you need to take care of your skin and external body surfaces.';

const ProductImage = (props) => {
    return <img src={props.image} />;
};

const ProductName = (props) => {
    return <h2>{props.name}</h2>;
};

const ProductDesc = (props) => {
    return <p>{props.description}</p>;
};

const Product = (props) => {

    return <div><ProductImage image={prod_img} /><ProductName name={prod_name} /><ProductDesc description={prod_description}/> </div> 
};



ReactDOM.render(<Product />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/28210/)

Comment: Yes, this was the answer I came to with Li357, but thank you very much for providing the retrospective. :)